# Apache is blocking tomcat's ROOT?

Tags: apache, tomcat, deployment

Ok, so I got apache and tomcat installed in one machine. I remember when I only had a fresh install of tomcat, that ROOT was deployed on mydomain.com but now that apache is running, it's apache's page that shows up. I got phpmyadmin installed and it works good. What I want to happen is to replace the default apache page with the ROOT.war that I placed on my tomcats webapps folder. As I understand, apache doesn't serve war files, just tomcat. How do I configure it so that they coexist in on one machine?

Answer (score 1):

Are both running on port 80? Apache is 80 by default and Tomcat is 8080.

If you want Apache to front tomcat for certain assets (like images) and certain paths (like the WAR) to be served from Tomcat - then you need to use mod_jk or mod_proxy within Apache to forward requests to the Tomcat when a certain URL pattern is matched.

If your question is different i.e. you want Apache and Tomcat to simply co-exist and server their own web pages - then the port needs to be different.

Comment: I want tomcat to front apache. I simply installed apache for phpmyadmin, and I installed tomcat for an app I was making in grails. Is there a way to use mod_jk to achieve the result I want?